# Why isn't srand seed changing results?

Tags: c++, srand

I hope the answer isn't too blatantly obvious, but I've looked around and can't seem to figure out why srand isn't changing the values in the bull_pen vector.
Every time it runs I get the same 4 integers.

I've read all about using the computer clock, making sure to only use srand once or outside of loops etc, including stdlib.h, but none of this helps.
Using user input as a seed seemed pretty easy but now I feel I'm missing some
basic understanding somewhere.
I apologize in advance if I have poor style etc - pretty new to C++ and programming in general. Thanks for the help.

```
#include "..\..\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int seed;
    cout << "Before the game begins, enter any integer.\nThis will generate a seed to randomize the game: ";
    cin >> seed;
    srand(seed);
    cout << "I have four numbers in a sequence for you to guess." << endl
        << "For every digit you guess that matches a digit in my sequence, I will tell you\nthat you guessed that many 'cows'." << endl
        << "For ever digit you guess that matches a digit AS WELL as matches the digits\nlocation in my sequence, I will say you guessed" << endl
        << "that many 'bulls'. Guessing all four 'bulls' wins the game.\n";

    while (1 == 1){

        vector<int>bull_pen(4);
        bull_pen[0] = randint(9);
        bull_pen[1] = randint(9);
        bull_pen[2] = randint(9);
        bull_pen[3] = randint(9);

        vector<int>guesses(4);
        int guess;


        int found = 0;
        int bulls = 0;
        int cows = 0;

        while (found != 1){
            vector<int>bull_pen_flags(4);

            cout << "Please enter your guesses: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); i++){
                cin >> guess;
                guesses[i] = guess;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < bull_pen.size(); i++){
                if (bull_pen[i] == guesses[i]) { bulls++; bull_pen_flags[i] = 1; }
            }

            if (bulls < 4){
                for (int guess_index = 0; guess_index < guesses.size(); guess_index++){
                    for (int bull_index = 0; bull_index < bull_pen.size(); bull_index++){
                        if (guess_index != bull_index && bull_pen_flags[bull_index] != 1){
                            if (guesses[guess_index] == bull_pen[bull_index]) { 
                            cows++;
                            bull_pen_flags[bull_index] = 1;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (cows > 0) cout << cows << " cow(s).\n";
                else cout << "No cows.\n";
                if (bulls > 0) cout << bulls << " bull(s).\n";
                else cout << "No bulls.\n";
                bulls = 0;
                cows = 0;
            }

            else found = 1;

        }
        cout << "You've guessed all four bulls; " << bull_pen[0] << bull_pen[1] << bull_pen[2] << bull_pen[3] << "\nYou win!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `randint`? How is it defined?

Comment: No idea. It's probably from the header file I'm using which I sourced from a book for learning c++. Is there a more universal alternative? I've seen use of rand, so I have a feeling replacing randint with rand could help?

Comment: If you input same `seed` then `rand()` will produce the same sequence everytime. That's how rand() is defined. Usually, you would use `srand(time(0));` to seed the so that everytime you run it, so that it produces different sequences.

Comment: Regardless of the different inputs for seed I get the same result, I've also tried srand(time(NULL)) and upon your advice srand(time(0)) and still the same results - scratching my head here..

Comment: I presume you are following Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice using C++"?

Comment: Next time create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ah I see how I could have been more helpful, thanks for the link.

Comment: @BrendanNolan: Then why do you assume it has anything to do with `srand`? Did you read the manual for `srand` to find out what it's for?

Comment: @KerrekSB Because as per instruction of said book for learning C++, I was led to believe by the author Bjrane Stroustrup that srand() could seed for randint().

Comment: Perfectly reasonable mistake. If you can't trust the inventor of the language as an authority on said language, who can you trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randint` is not a standard library function. It is a function from the header you are using, which is not part of the standard library. It is only part of Bjarne Stroustrup's introductory library for his "Programming Principles and Practice using C++". The source file is [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h), and the definition of that function is as follows:

```
inline int randint(int min, int max) { static default_random_engine ran; return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }

inline int randint(int max) { return randint(0, max); }
```

As you can see, it uses `default_random_engine` for random number generation, which is part of the C++11 standard library. `srand` has no effect on this engine. There is a way to seed it, but Bjarne hasn't exposed it through the interface he provided (I think he's just trying to keep things as simple as possible in this library, as it is only meant to be used for introductory purposes).

If you want a random number generator you can seed, then you can continue to use `srand` for seeding, but use `rand()` for generating your numbers. Better yet, you can use the same engine that the `randint` function uses.

```
std::default_random_engine engine(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 9);

int x = dist(engine);
```

Comment: Hmmm...the book says: *You can get four random digits by calling the random num­ ber generator randint(10) from std_lib_facilities.h four times. You will note that if you run that program repeatedly, it will pick the same se­quence of four digits each time you start the program. To avoid that, ask the user to enter a number (any number) and call srand(n) where n is the number the user entered before calling randint(10). Such an n is called a seed, and different seeds give different sequences of random numbers.*

Comment: @BlueMoon: You must be using the older edition, which uses `rand`. If the newer edition still says that, then it is an error.

Comment: Yes, I have the old one. I'll verify what you said when I get the newer version :D

Comment: If the latest edition is to be the second, then I have it and it says:
"You will note that if you run that
program repeatedly, it will pick the same sequence of four digits each time you start the
program. To avoid that, ask the user to enter a number (any number) and call srand(n) where n
is the number the user entered before calling randint(10). Such an n is called a seed, and
different seeds give different sequences of random numbers."

In any case, rand() effectively solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: @BrendanNolan: Does it say "Using C++11 and C++14" in a white circle on the cover?

Comment: Then it is an error. Looks like that was just copied from the older edition and not properly verified.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline int randint(int min, int max,int seed) { static default_random_engine ran(seed);
    return uniform_int_distribution<>{min, max}(ran); }

inline int randint(int max,int seed) { return randint(0, max,seed); }
```

You can modify the header file, just like above, to pass seed to the default engine. Here is the version of my program

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main (){
    cout << "Enter any number to start the game";
    int seed;
    cin >> seed;
    vector<int> v(4);

    // For generating randon numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v[i] = randint(9,seed);

    // For generating random four different digits

    for (int i = 1 ; i < v.size(); i++){
        for (int j = i; j < v.size(); j++){
            while (v[i-1] == v [j])
                v[i-1] = randint(9,seed);
        }
    }
    int bull = 0, cow = 0, tries = 0;
    cout << "I have a four digit number can you guess it??\n";
    cout << "lets start the game!!!\n ";
    int number;
    while (bull != 4){
        tries++;
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;
        cout << "Guess the number: ";
        cin >> number;
        if (number > 1000 && number < 9999){

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
                if (v[i] == number % 10){ // to see digit is correct
                    if (i == v.size()-1)// to see 1's position is correct
                        bull++;
                    else cow++;
                }
                if (v[i] == (number % 100) / 10){ // to see digit is correct
                    if (i == v.size()-2)// to see 10's position is correct
                        bull++;
                    else cow++;
                }
                if (v[i] == (number / 100) % 10){ // to see digit is correct
                    if (i == v.size()-3)// to see 100's position is correct
                        bull++;
                    else cow++;
                }
                if (v[i] == number / 1000){ // to see digit is correct
                    if (i == v.size()-4)// to see 1000's position is correct
                        bull++;
                    else cow++;
                }

        }

        cout << "Digits correct = " << bull+cow << "\n" << "Position correct = " << bull << "\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "Enter only four digit numbers\n";
    }
    cout << "CONGRATS!!!..YOU GUESSED THE NUMBER IN  " << tries << " tries\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Along with the value, pass the seed to the default engine ran for initialisation. I hope it resolves the issue